# AJAX chat submission only working with $(document).keypress()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

There's an input field for my ajax chat which should send data on enter press.

```
$("#chatfield").keypress(function(e) {
if(e.which == 13) {
   chatsend($('#chatfield').val());
}
});
```

The code above won't work, only

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
if(e.which == 13) {
   chatsend($('#chatfield').val());
}
});
```

But I don't want the code to listen the whole document for keypress event.

The input field has an id although it is not wrapped in a form element.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is to delegate.

```
$(document).on('keypress', '#chatfield', function(e) {
   if(e.which == 13) {
      chatsend($('#chatfield').val());
   }
});
```